# Using *args to call python function an undefined number of times

Tags: python

I have defined a function `createDictionary` that takes a file, extracts keys from that file and uses those keys to index a data value from a matrix. This is then returned with the indexes used as a key and value retrieved as a value in a python dictionary.

My goal is to write a `getData` function that will call and run `createDictionary` a certain number of times based on how many matrices and other args the user passes to it. The more manual version of what I want to do is below.

```
def getData(bedfile, matrix1, start1, end1, matrix2, start2, end2, matrix3, start3, end3, bedfilesep = "\t", matrixsep = "\t"):
    x = createDictionary(bedfile, matrix1, start1, end1, bedfilesep, matrixsep)
    y = createDictionary(bedfile, matrix2, start2, end2, bedfilesep, matrixsep)
    z = createDictionary(bedfile, matrix3, start3, end3, bedfilesep, matrixsep)

    x.update(y)
    x.update(z)

    return x.values()
```

Ideally I would be able to pass any number of `matrix#`, `start#`, and `end#` arguments and run this function for the number of occurrences of such.

Comment: Why not pass in *a sequence* of those parameters? A list with nested tuples, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as passing your arguments as a `list`, so

```
getData(bedfile, matrix1, ... , matrix2, ...)
```

would become

```
getData(bedfile, [matrix1, matrix2], ....)
```

Then in your `getData` function, you could process these as

```
x = {}
for matrix, start, end in zip(matrices, starts, ends):
    x.update(createDictionary(bedfile, matrix, start, end, bedfilesep, matrixsep)
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I implemented it using your recommendation and it works just as I hoped. Many thanks

Comment: @cubedNnoobed, I can't help but noticed you posted the same comment to Pavel's answer.  Please mark the method you actually used as the "accepted" answer (the green check mark)

Comment: I used yours practically verbatim but both of you had the idea to pass a list of arguments. I wasn't aware of the green check mark until now thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

actually you want to use a different data structure.
whenever you find yourself defining x1, x2, x3 ... x913 etc, consider using lists!

the function would look like this:

```
def getData(bedfile, matrixlist, bedfilesep = "\t", matrixsep = "\t"):
  x = createDictionary(bedfile, matrixlist[0][0], matrixlist[0][1], matrixlist[0][2], bedfilesep, matrixsep)
  y = createDictionary(bedfile, matrixlist[1][0], matrixlist[1][1], matrixlist[1][2], bedfilesep, matrixsep)
  z = createDictionary(bedfile, matrixlist[2][0], matrixlist[2][1], matrixlist[2][2], bedfilesep, matrixsep)
  ...
```

and you would need to pack your matrices into the list e.g. by storing them in tuples:

```
mylist = []
mylist.append((m1, s1, e1))
mylist.append((m12, 12, 33))
```

then you can pass the whole list at once by calling

```
getData(bedfile, mylist)
```

Comment: Yes I see that this makes a lot more sense and I have now implemented it this way. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Consider just passing them in as three separate lists for matrix, start, and end, or a list of tupled triplets of the three. Then use a for loop or list comprehension to run for every set of them.
Using *args **kwargs for unordered, heterogenous argument lists seems not ideal.